# AWS IoT MQTT vs Websockets on Elastic Beanstalk for web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mqtt, aws-iot

What are a basic pros/cons of using AWS IoT with MQTT over Websockets running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

My basic concerns: performance, pricing, management efforts and implementation effort as well.

Has anyone met similar dilemma?

Comment: I am using MQTT over WebSocket for IOT project. But I didn't use AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: There are three options MQTT, Websockets, and MQTT over WebSocket. Among which do you need the comparison? More info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html